# Rails Form Object Returns Object ID in mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid3

I have the below form which works absolute fine but when submitted the :event field returns an ID in the mailer, any ideas how to prevent this?

#### Form

```
<%= simple_form_for @sponsorship_inquiry, :method => :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :spam, as: :hidden %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :phone %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :job_title %>
    <%= f.input :company %>
    <%= f.input :event, :collection => Event.where(:end_date.gt => Date.today, :is_live => 'true') %>
    <%= f.input :message, as: :text, :input_html => { :cols => 5, :rows => 6 } %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

#### Mailer

```
Name: <%= @sponsorship_inquiry.name %>
Phone: <%= @sponsorship_inquiry.name %>
E-Mail: <%= @sponsorship_inquiry.email %>
Job Title: <%= @sponsorship_inquiry.job_title %>
Company: <%= @sponsorship_inquiry.company %>
Event: <%= @sponsorship_inquiry.event %>
Message: <%= @sponsorship_inquiry.message %>
```

#### Controller

```
def new
    @sponsorship_inquiry = SponsorshipInquiry.new
end

def create
    # Hidden field for bots/spiders
    redirect_to new_inquiry_path and return if params[:spam].present?
    @sponsorship_inquiry = SponsorshipInquiry.new(params[:sponsorship_inquiry])
    if @sponsorship_inquiry.valid?
        SponsorshipInquiryMailer.admin(@sponsorship_inquiry).deliver
        redirect_to sponsorship_inquiries_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

Comment: How is `sponsorship_inquiry` and `event` associated ? If they are not associated then you will have to find the event with that id and  pass it your mailer. If they are associated already then show us the association and you model code to be able to know whats going on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need your SponsorshipInquiry model.

If you have

```
class SponsorshipInquiry < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :event

end
```

try send `<%= @sponsorship_inquiry.event.name %>` or whatever )

Or you need to parse needed value from the form if "event" is only field not associated with Event model.

IMHO

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "can I modify the form so that I automatically (magically?) get an object as a param?", the answer is definetly no.

What you have to do is to search the event object in the database based on the received id.

Comment: The select dropdown in the form shows the event titles but the email returns the ID. So my question is why?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include html code generated and explain exactly the behaviour that you are expecting? (a question is not a question if you just write code there expecting the people to guess what's going on and how it should behave)